# std::deque - изменить внутренний размер "вектора"

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я понимаю std::deque - это некий гибрид списка и вектора, то есть это список векторов. Вопрос, позволяет ли std::deque - изменять размер этого внутреннего вектора ?

Answer (score 1):

Не верно вы понимаете.  std::deque   реализован как отдельный, самостоятельные шаблон класса. Это такой же полноценный контейнер, как и  списки и вектора, для которого реализованы свои собственные итераторы, а элементы распределят собственный распределитель(по умолчанию, конечно стандартный). Он реализован так, чтобы можно было более эффективно работать с концами(вставка и удаление). И такие **адаптеры**, как стандартные очереди и стеки, используют именно std::deque ( понятно почему).

Comment: спасибо, но, тогда я не понимаю, чем std:;deque отличается от std::list - по крайней мере в плане, как Вы написали - "Он реализован так, чтобы можно было более эффективно работать с концами(вставка и удаление)". Список тоже в плане удаления и вставки с концов работает эффективно.

Comment: в теории да, список работает эффективно, но у него есть пара фатальных недостатков: скорость индексации (у деки можно сделать близкой к O(1) ) и фрагментация памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, именно поэтому, из за того, что у std::deque быстрее индексация, я и предположил, что внутри некоторое подобие списка векторов. Но, странно, что нельзя при создании std::deque - задать размер этого "вектора". Ведь теоретически размером этого "вектора" можно регулировать и скорость индексации и фрагментацию.

Comment: @Optimus1, А как вы думаете, стоит использовать  технику, которая умеет  изменять любое звено цепочки, для того, чтобы только снять(вставить одно звено из(в) любого конца ? А ведь можно это проделать двумя пальцами...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, не совсем понял вопрос.

Comment: @Optimus1 - в том и сила deque, что разработчики библиотеки должны обеспечить гарантии, но внутренний мир могут спрятать. Это позволяет делать чудные оптимизации внутри. к примеру, никто не мешает реализовать deque внутри как slist - небольшое дерево, листя которого - списки. Правда глубину нужно будет ограничить, иначе индексация будет не O(1),  а O(ln), но работать будет. Или, к примеру, можно взять `map<int, vector<T>>` - главное аккуратно все написать.

Comment: @Optimus1,
 Значит я плохо объясняю.....

Comment: @Optimus1, по вашей логике и списки не нужны _ можно использовать только вектор_

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, удивлен :)  Это где Вы такую мою логику увидели ?? Это точно был мираж.

Comment: Да реально и в самом деле реализация может быть построена на списке векторов, по крайней мере в книгах встречается... Но это не значит, что это именно так. Это дело реализации — как именно его реализовать.

Comment: вполне может быть, что через несколько лет производители процессоров/контроллеров памяти скажут - " мы можем деку на уровне инструкций сделать" и тут код, который написан на интерфейсе deque сразу заработает и хорошо заработает. А код, который пытается управлять внутренностями  - будет в печали.

Comment: @KoVadim, очень интересно, небольшой простой тест сделал, сначала заполнил list и deq элементами, а потом в цикле удалял все элемента через pop_front с замером времени и получилось, что deq удаляет быстрее списка в среднем в 4 раза.

Comment: Потому что new/delete malloc/free очень могут быть затратными. Особенно на мелких объектах